# Displaying php query in column instead of row

Tags: php, html, css, postgresql

Hey guys i have a postgres database to which i am connecting and fetching data from using php. I am a newbie to php. But anyway i have this as my query

```
$sql = "SELECT to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymm') as month,min(a.calldate) as   start_time,max(a.calldate) as end_time,
         ceil(SUM (a.CALLDURATION::integer) / 60) AS minutes,
         COUNT (DISTINCT a.IDENTIFIANT) AS distinct_callers,
a.zoneiddest as country_code,b.country
FROM cdr_data a,COUNTRY_CODES b
WHERE  a.CALLSUBCLASS = '002'
     AND  a.CALLCLASS = '008'
and a.zoneiddest::integer > 0
AND SUBSTR (a.CALLEDNUMBER, 1, 2) NOT IN
('77', '78', '75', '70', '71', '41', '31', '39', '76','79')
and not substr(a.zoneiddest , 1 ,3) in ('254','255','256','211','257','250','256')
and trim(a.zoneiddest)  = trim(b.country_code)
GROUP BY to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymm') ,a.zoneiddest,b.country
ORDER BY 1";
```

And i have this to return the data that is queried:

```
// iterate over result set
// print each row
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "Month: " . $row[0] . "<br />";
     echo "Start Time: " . $row[1] . "<br />";
     echo "End Time: " . $row[2] . "<br />";
     echo "Minutes: " . $row[3] . "<br />";
     echo "Distinct Callers: " . $row[4] . "<br />";
     echo "Country Code: " . $row[5] . "<br />";
     echo "Country: " . $row[6] . "<br />";

  }
```

This returns my data in this format

```
Month: 201212
Start Time: 2012-12-28 15:51:04
End Time: 2012-12-28 15:51:04
Minutes: 0
Distinct Callers: 1
Country Code: 44
Country: United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland
```

But would love to have this data in the table where month, start time, end time, minutes, distinct callers, country code and country are the column headers in the table. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code below. Let me know if my understanding of your requirements is incorrect.

```
   <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Month</td>
    <td>Start Time</td>
    <td>End Time</td>
    <td>Minutes</td>
    <td>Distinct Callers</td>
    <td>Country Code/td>
    <td>Country</td>
    </tr>
   <?php 
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<tr>';
         echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
     echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### dont forget to add loop

```
echo "<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1' style='background-color: #D7D2D2;font-size:12px;font-family:Tahoma;'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:11px' align='left'>Month</th>";
echo "<th style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:11px' align='left'>Start Time</th>";
echo "<th style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:11px' align='left'>End Time</th>";
echo "<th style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:11px' align='left'>Minutes</th>";
echo "<th style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:11px' align='left'>Distinct Callers</th>";
echo "<th style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:11px' align='left'>Country Code</th>";
echo "<th style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:11px' align='left'>Country</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>$row[0]</td>";
echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>$row[1]</td>";
echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>$row[2]</td>";
echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>$row[3]</td>";
echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>$row[4]</td>";
echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>$row[5]</td>";
echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>$row[6]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Yes this will work thanks alot. This has some styling which it a plus. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
$output = "<table>";
$output .= "<tr>";
$output .= "<td> Month </td>";
$output .= "<td> Start Time </td>";
$output .= "<td> End Time </td>";
$output .= "<td> Minutes </td>";
$output .= "<td> Distinct Callers </td>";
$output .= "<td> Country Codes </td>";
$output .= "<td> Country </td>";
$output .= "</tr>";

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
     $output .= "<tr>";
     $output .= "<td>". $row[0] . "</td>";
     $output .= "<td>". $row[1] . "</td>";
     $output .= "<td>". $row[2] . "</td>";
     $output .= "<td>". $row[3] . "</td>";
     $output .= "<td>". $row[4] . "</td>";
     $output .= "<td>". $row[5] . "</td>";
     $output .= "<td>". $row[6] . "</td>";
     $output .= "</tr>";

  }
  $output .= "</table>";

  echo $output;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>Month</td>";
       echo "<td>Start Time</td>";
       echo "<td>End Time</td>";
       echo "<td>Minutes</td>";
       echo "<td>Distinct Callers</td>";
       echo "<td>Country Code</td>";
       echo "<td>Country</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[5]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row[6]."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```